# Regex returning different result on the same string in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am extracting ZIP codes from a list of strings using REGEXP_REPLACE in Oracle. When I test the regex on the string, the ZIP code is correctly extracted. However, when I move the regex to production on a VIEW in Oracle, I get different results from the regex on the exact same string.

The following string appears twice in my VIEW :

```
;2;5;1;1;Company Name;1;Location;1;12 Street;1;City, US-IL 13012;1;US;
```

I'm using the following statement within the VIEW to capture the ZIP code

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (tb."ADDRESS", '.*([A-Z]{2}[0-9]?-[A-Z0-9]* ?|, ?)([^;]{0,10}|);[0-9];[A-Z]{2};', '\2 ')
```

- On the first occurence of the string, the regex extracts "US-IL"
- On the first occurence of the string, the regex extracts "13012"

Any idea why I'd get different results from the exact same regex ? I've tried to debug it, to rewrite the regex but I'm stumped. I would expect the regex to return "13012" for both occurences of this string.

N.B. The regex needs to be flexible enough to pick up ZIPs and Postcodes for many different countries, my dataset is not just for US addresses.

Comment: In a comment on an answer you said you compared the two values side-by-side and there are no hidden characters; how did you verify that, with the `dump()` function? It *might* show something if you copy and paste both strings and their dumps into your question. Also how is the view generating those strings in the first place - and can you see the same issue if you query the base data instead of the view? What else is different - database versions or patch levels maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to extract the part of the string you need.

Example:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '\s+(\d{5});[0-9];[A-Z]{2};', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/vD5RaY/1) and the [Oracle demo](https://rextester.com/JXEKPS82493). The regex graph:

[image]

**Regex**

- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d{5})` - Group 1 (the result)" five digits
- `;[0-9];[A-Z]{2};` - `;`, a digit, `;`, 2 uppercase letters, `;`.

If you plan to stick to your specific regex, please note that the real value is in Group 2. So, you need to specify `2` as the last argument to `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 
      '.*([A-Z]{2}[0-9]?-[A-Z0-9]* ?|, ?)([^;]{0,10}|);[0-9];[A-Z]{2};',
      1, 1, NULL, 2)
```

See [this Oracle demo](https://rextester.com/XGNB76792).

Comment: Thank Wiktor. I did try to do this with REGEXP_SUBSTR but could not get it to work. There are zipcodes from many different countries all following distinct formats. The structure of each string is also different - sometimes the zip appears at the end, at other times it appear in the middle etc. I found the backreference capability in REGEXP_REPLACE offered more flexibility to allow for the different cases. Would I be able to reach the same result using REGEXP_SUBSTR , given those complexities ?

Comment: @duraq You may rely on `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, but what are the pattern requirements then? Please explain. Note if you can't explain the format of the ZIP code in plain verbal rules then there might be no solution at all, regex is only useful when you have a clear set of contextual/char type rules you need to follow.

Comment: There is a pattern which I've captured in the regex in my original post. When I test it on regex101.com it correctly captures 100% of the ZIPs (US and other countries) in my data. The problem is that when moving the regex to Oracle, it correctly captures all ZIPs except for this one case above. If you can confirm that this is due to using `REGEXP_REPLACE` instead `REGEXP_SUBSTR` then I will see how I can incorporate my regex within a `REGEXP_SUBSTR` statement.

Comment: @duraq Well, I only see what you posted and there is nothing that fishy, but a rule of thumb is: you replace when you need to modify a string and you extract when you need to get  a specific part of  a string. I added your regex demo, test for a bit and see for yourself.

Comment: first of all, thanks for your guidance on this. I took the SQL statement you provided and while it works fine on the regex demo - once I plug that into my View SQL, I get two different results "US-DE" for the first record and "13012" for the second record. I just don't get - I put the strings side-by-side and confirm that they are the exact same (no hidden characters anywhere, etc).

Comment: @duraq There is no `US-DE` substring on the Web page other than in your comment, I can't help you more.